# How should I do cross-browser solutions?

Tags: cross-browser

I just want to know when you guys do **cross-browser solutions**, do you think about old browsers and by that I mean the version of those browsers... I've been struggling with it and I'm not really sure how to proceed.

An example is the **"contenteditable"** HTML attribute, it works in all browsers but older versions of some browsers does not work. should I care about it?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

I generally only worry about the browsers our customers use (which I can find in Google Analytics) for the past quarter or two. Once I have a list of all the browsers they are on, I'll then reduce complexity a bit by choosing only two versions of that browser to test on.

Sometimes I'll solicit feedback from the business side of the organization on what browsers we want to officially support but for the most part browsers update automatically and most customers are on relatively new browsers. (The challenge is when you still have customers on IE which doesn't auto-update).

Comment: Thanks, it's because I'm building my first web application and I'm not really sure how people do it ... and I really want this to work as much similar in all browsers as possible.